# SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3 won’t install

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, service-pack

I am trying to install SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3 and it keeps failing. Comes back with the following:

`Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - Update 'Service Pack 3 for SQL Server Database Services 2005 ENU (KB955706)' could not be installed. Error code 1603.`

The detailed dump reveals the following:

```
MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:776]: Note: 1: 1729 MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:776]: Transforming table Error.   
MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:776]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:792]: Transforming table Error.   
MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:792]: Transforming table Error.    
MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:792]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:792]: Transforming table Error.    
MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:792]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:792]: Transforming table Error.    
MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:792]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:792]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:792]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:807]: Transforming table Error.    
MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:807]: Transforming table Error.    
MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:807]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:807]: Transforming table Error.  
MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:807]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:807]: Transforming table Error.  
MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:807]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 MSI (s) (90:C8) [13:50:17:807]: Product: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 -- Configuration failed.
```

Does it mean anything to anybody?

Btw, this Q originally came from SO (936895)

Comment: i got a similar gripe from wsus about an SP I applied by hand and when I try to run it from wsus to clear it, it fails. odd.

Comment: Angry- The useful part of the error message is directly above what you pasted (what you have just says that the MSI installer had a problem). Is there a <Func Name> section and/or more information about which component is failing to install (and therefore messing up the whole install)?

Comment: The Database Services part failed.

Comment: Have you re-downloaded the SP3 bits in case there was some sort of corruption?

Comment: i have found that most sql install problems differentiate slightly but all have the same route problem. better explained..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This fixed it for me

http://www.sqlnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/topic23830.aspx

Essentially:-

Remove the following registry subkeys that store SID settings:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL.X\Setup\SQLGroup 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL.X\Setup\AGTGroup 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL.X\Setup\FTSGroup 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL.X\Setup\ASGroup

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue when you have installed a named instance in a location other than the default - possibly in a folder named "MSSQLServer".

You might be able to move the instance to another location and complete the installation.

"MSSQLServer" is the default service name of the Database Services component.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem directly related, but may be worth a shot:

From [MS KB 925336](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925336):

> When you try to install a large
>   Microsoft Windows Installer (.msi)
>   package or a large Microsoft Windows
>   Installer patch (.msp) package on a
>   computer that is running Microsoft
>   Windows Server 2003 or Microsoft
>   Windows XP, you receive the following
>   error message:  Error 1718. File
>   FileName was rejected by digital
>   signature policy.

It's the single most common problem I've had installing Service Packs on SQL Servers.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem yesterday and found a different solution.

> Product: Microsoft SQL Server 2005
>   Express Edition - Update 'GDR 4053 for
>   SQL Server Database Services 2005 ENU
>   (KB970892)' could not be installed.
>   Error code 1603.

I was able to get SP3 to install by modifying just this single registry value:

- **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
  Server\MSSQL.1\Setup`**

  - *If you have multiple instances of SQL Server installed, the key
    might be different for you.*
- Find the **`Resume`** REG_DWORD and change its value from 1 to 0.
- Try installing the update again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure permission on the Microsoft SQL Server folder contained the SQLServer2005MSSQLUser$ - whether user is missing in the permissions. Also Make sure that no other service or application is automatically starting SQL Server service(s) when they are not running. Then stop the SQL Server services and install SP3 by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue for 2005 SP4 on a SCOM 2007 server.  The Report Server would fail on upgrade with similar issues.  In this case I shutdown all SQL services and SCOM services and it ran correctly.